# Getting AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pycharm

```
python
```

*I am reading CSV into Pyspark Dataframe named 'InputDataFrame' using* :

```
InputDataFrame = spark.read.csv(path=file_path,inferSchema=True,ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace=True,header=True)
```

*After reading I am using* :

```
InputDataFrame.schema.names
```

*to find column names. But I am getting below logs on console* :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/snap/pycharm-community/143/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_xml.py", line 284, in frame_vars_to_xml
    xml += var_to_xml(v, str(k), evaluate_full_value=eval_full_val) 

  File "/snap/pycharm-community/143/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_xml.py", line 384, in var_to_xml
    xml_shape = ' shape="%s"' % make_valid_xml_value(str(v.shape))  

  File "/home/ajinkya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1300, in __getattr__
    "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))  

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'shape'  
Unexpected error, recovered safely.
```

*Can anyone explain why is this happening ? Also is there any alternative way to find inferred schema of Pyspark Dataframe*

'''
Using Pycharm IDE for development
'''

Comment: You can use `InputDataFrame.printSchema()`

Comment: could you please provide your code? According to the error message `File "/snap/pycharm-community/143/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_xml.py", line 384, in var_to_xml
    xml_shape = ' shape="%s"' % make_valid_xml_value(str(v.shape)) ` you call v.shape in line 384 with v being a spark dataframe and spark dataframes just don't have an attribute shape

Comment: @Paul I understand that internally that shape attribute is called and it's not present . But the thing is I am using below code :
```InputDataFrame.schema.names  ,
type(InputDataFrame)  ,
InputDataFrame.select("Col1").show()  ,
InputDataFrame.select("Col2").show()  ,
InputDataFrame.select("Col3").show()  ,
```
None of above are working

Comment: @MaFF yes InputDataFrame.printSchema() works , but still has issues . refer above comment.

Comment: sorry I got that wrong.  
Do you run via debug in pycharm? Is your spark session local or are you using some remote execution on a cluster?

Comment: @Paul yes I am using pycharm to debug and pyspark interpreter locally

Comment: The issue I was facing was because of '.' in my data's column names. Remember to replace it with something else like '_' . Thanks
My issue is resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem happening on some code that was working perfectly fine after migrating to the latest Pycharm version.

I assume you are using the latest Pycharm version (2019.2). I don't have an explanation to why this is causing the issue but installing the older Pycharm 2019.1.4 fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Will try doing that .

Comment: I can confirm that using the older version (2019.1.4) fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I updated PyCharm to 2019.2.1 and now it's working fine. Thank you Ben so much!

Answer (score 2):

Agreed, run this on pycharm 2019.2 with no problem. Put a break point somewhere, debug and error will happen

```
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    pdf = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['asdf', 'fdsa'], 'B': [1, 2]})
    sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
    print(pdf)
    sdf.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Ben.  The new version PyCharm code is expecting a Pandas DataFrame which contains a 'shape' attribute and not an RDD DataFrame (which does not).  You will need to roll back to an older version or wait for JetBrains to issue a fix.